# Разделить прямоугольник на несколько фигур

Tags: алгоритм

Как разделить прямоугольник на 6 фигур (2 квадрата, 2 горизонтальных прямоугольника, 2 вертикальных прямоугольника)? 
Как рассчитать это на автомате, что бы указав количество каждого типа фигуры и размеры разбиваемого прямоугольника получить такой результат?
[image: Изображение разбитое на части]
Подскажите формулы или может уже где-то есть реализация на php?

Пример ожидаемого результата:

```
function cutRectangle($rectangleWidth, $rectangleHeight, $countSquare, $countHorizontalRectangle, $countVerticalRectangle){... return $image;}
```

Comment: Вот вы сначала создайте алгоритм или найдите пример решения этой задачи, а уже потом приставляйте к ней тэг PHP. Это алгоритмическая задача, изначально не имеющая отношение ни к какому языку для разработки.

Comment: Я и обратился сюда за помощью разработки алгоритма, иначе бы не писал ничего здесь.

Comment: совершенно не понятно откуда брать соотношения сторон прямоугольников

Comment: допустим, вам дан прямоугоьник 5х6 и вам надо разделить его на 3 квадрата. Что должен сделать алгоритм?

Comment: Размеры изображения передаются в функцию изначально вручную. Дальше, если необходимо разбить прямоугольник на три квадрата - то функция делит его на три относительно равных квадрата

Comment: @tym32167 для таких случаев очевидно, что алгоритм либо должен прекращать работу заведомо, либо подобрать правильное количество фигур каждого типа

Comment: @ampawd ну это вам очевидно, а мне не очевидно, потому я и спросил у автора